# HoneyC installation

Tags: ruby, rubygems, windows-xp, installation, vmware

I'm now using HoneyC version 1.3.0 in a Windows XP Professional environment inside a VMware. But I can't seem to run its UnitTester.rb or its HoneyC.rb with default configurations. I keep getting the following errors. I installed Ruby latest version, RDE and RubyGems inside. Could it be directory mismatch or something? Please kindly suggest or advise me on solving this, because I can't find much information online as it is quite an old Honey Client application and none of the solutions given work for me.

```
Errors output
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\HoneyC-1.3.0\HoneyC-1.3.0>ruby UnitTester.rb
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load --
test/unit/testsuite (LoadError)
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from UnitTester.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What's written in line one of UnitTester.rb? Apparently it is requiring some missing lib. Probably you just have to install the gem with the mentioned lib.